# Activating an element's listener inside a div without activating the div's listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to be able to activate an element's listener without activating the listener of the div that contains my element.

```
$('body').on('click', '.thiscoll', function(){
    if (type === "form") {
        hidePanels();
        $('#navbar-pannel').show();
    }
});

$('#main_container').on('click', 'a', function(){
    hidePanels();
    $('#custom-nav').show();

    $('#l-name').html("New link name");
    $('#l-destination').html("New link destination");
});
```

The first listener is on my div, while the second listener is on my links that are contained into my div. When I click on a link, it first triggers the 'a' listener, then the '.thiscoll' listener, while I only want to trigger the 'a' listener.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Honestly, this is way to much to read. Please state your problem concisely and leave out all the story telling. You'll do best to include a minimal working example showing the problem.

Comment: simply add an element like an "a" tag or a "button" in your column and add the columEdit listener on it and not on column itself

Comment: I made a quick reply that is more concise.
Sim1-81 - I want it to be user friendly, it's for people that aren't used to programming. I prefer it to be triggered when they click on the column itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short, you want to stop event propagation. Something like

```
$('a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    // and possibly do something else you require
});
```

should do.

Comment: It actually stopped the parent's listener to be triggered. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you want is possible. With events in Javascript we have this nice thing called *event capturing* and *event bubbling*. By default, browsers will register events in the bubbling phase.

For you, this means that the target you click will have its event handlers fired first. Then its parent's. Then its parent's parent's and so on. You can read more about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Bubbling_and_capturing_explained)

To stop this propagation, you can use the `stopPropagtion` method on the `Event`-object. The `Event` object is supplied as the first argument in your event listener:

```js
const main = document.querySelector('.main');
const button = document.querySelector('.button');
const stopPropagation = document.getElementById('stopPropagation');

main.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('Clicked on main'));

button.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  if (stopPropagation.checked) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
  }
  console.log('clicked button');
});
```

```html
<input id="stopPropagation" type="checkbox">
<label for="stopPropagation">stopPropagation</label>

<div class="main">
  Hello, World
  <button class="button">Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer. The code that Mbojko gave me was as simple as one line and perfectly fixed my problem but I loved the explanations.